# When is session state initialized in the ASP.NET pipeline

Tags: asp.net, session-state

I have an IHTTPModule with an event handler for AuthorizeRequest. I would like to access the Session object but it is not yet initialized. Which event should I subscribe to in order to have the session object available as early as possible in the pipeline?

Answer (score 7):

You needd HttpApplication.PostAcquireRequestState event -
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.postacquirerequeststate.aspx. Also there is a HttpApplication.AcquireRequestState event. Don't forget to check if your handler implements IRequiresSessionState or IReadOnlySessionState, otherwise it will throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState and subscribe to PostAcquireRequestState but I still see a null value for the session.