# In which stage or event is the Session state initiated in Asp.net request life cycle

Tags: asp.net, session, page-lifecycle

All, I knew the [life-cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) of the asp.net application, But I didn't know when the `Session` object of `HttpContext.current` is initiated and ready to be used. thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is session state initialized in the ASP.NET pipeline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228822/when-is-session-state-initialized-in-the-asp-net-pipeline)

Comment: Look at the text in the link - When an instance of HttpApplication is created, any configured modules are also created. For instance, if the application is configured to do so, ASP.NET creates a SessionStateModule module.

Comment: All,like the answer says. In the pipe-line mode of asp.net, So the `Session` would be available after through the `HttpApplication.PostAcquireRequestState` event of the first `HttpModule`! right ?thanks.

Comment: I mean, It is not necessary to handle the `HttpApplication.PostAcquireRequestState` in every `HttpModule` whenever I want to use the session in the `HttpMoudule`. right ?

Comment: @JayWalker,@shahkalpesh please review my comments